# Why is my String splitting by a regex not working?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have an input string, e.g. "5+3".
Now I want to split it by a regex:

```
String[] rawTokens = input.split("\\+|\\-|\\*|/|\\d+");
```

The tokens array should now be [5, +, 3] but it is empty.

What's the problem?

Comment: You're splitting on digits and `+`. Split characters are not included in the result.

Comment: Read the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29 Strings are split *around* matches. This means that the matches themselves are not within the array

Comment: Thank you Dragondraikk.
How can I then split *by* matches?

Comment: You could use a Matcher. `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\+|\\-|\\*|/|\\d+").matcher(input); while(m.find()) println(m.group());`

Comment: I'm sorry. I searched that topic already here on SO but I didn't find that thread.

Comment: Have you considered a tokenizer/lexical analyzer or parsing tool? Looks like you're trying to parse the equation to then process it, in which case, you'd be better off getting an abstract syntax tree or something. (In other words, you're basically writing a compiler or runtime here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is three-fold:

1. Input matching the pattern passed to split is *consumed* (thrown away) and what's left between the matches is returned as an array
2. Your pattern matches *every character* of the input, so it's all consumed (thrown away) leaving only blanks (zero-length strings) to fill the array
3. Trailing blanks are silently truncated from the returned array

Now then, how to fix...

You need a pattern that does *not* match any input characters because you don't want anything consumed. Instead, you need to match *between* the terms you want to extract. You need look arounds:

```
String[] rawTokens = input.split("\\b");
```

This pattern matches "word boundaries" (in this case between non-digits and digits, or visa versa).

See [live demo](http://ideone.com/siMuM3) producing the output you want.

Comment: Thank you!
I did it with a Matcher.

Comment: @AndiixAndii I just realised the regex can be greatly simplified - see updated answer, in case you prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

To split the string you could use:

```
"\\+|\\*|/|-|\\d+"
```

or

```
"\\d+|[+*/-]"
```

---

```
    try {
        String input = "5+3";
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+|\\*|/|-|\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            list.add(matcher.group());
        }
        String[] rawTokens = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rawTokens);
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    }
```

Comment: thank you i did it this way